# Create a collection by associating two id's of two different object

Tags: java, android, kotlin, collections

I have two list of objects.

members: List,
membersHistory: List

Both of these objects have an "id" field. I want to create a list by joining both of these lists by making sure the "id" field of one is associated to the other object that have the same id. Both, object have different data but they are for specific member. Just need to pair them somehow to create a collection.

I started out something like below. But, I think I need to map them by "id" first before zipping them. Thank you!

```
members.zip(membersHistory).mapIndexed {_, pair ->
val (member, memberHistory) = pair 




}
```

Comment: I think it would still face the issue of not having id differentiation; but you could make a custom Tuple<T1,T2> class or use java's Pair<E1,E2> if you're on a new enough version

Comment: Is this a One-To-One relationship? Each member object has one, and only one, history object?

Comment: Yes, it's a one to one relationship. The list just comes in different order. I want to make sure I associate the member with the specific member history.

Comment: You should state that fact as an edit to your Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to create a list of pairs of the items.

1. For each item in the first list, find a corresponding item in the second list with the same idea and pair them if found. `mapNotNull` will cause it to skip items that have no match in the second list.

```
val combination: List<Pair<Member, MemberHistory>> = members
    .mapNotNull { member -> memberHistories.firstOrNull { it.id == member.id }?.let { member to it } }
```

2. To do this in *O(n)*, you can create a map with the IDs as keys from one of the sources lists using `associateBy`.

```
val memberHistoryById = memberHistories.associateBy { it.id }
val combination = members.mapNotNull { member -> memberHistoryById[member.id]?.let { member to it } }
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was what I needed for my specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, though it hasn't been stated explicitly in the question, the `id` is the ID of a Member, so there will be no two objects in the `members` list with the same `id` value.

For quick lookup of Member by ID, I'd recommend creating 2 maps:

```java
// Examples in Java
Map<Integer, Member> memberById = members.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Member::getId, Function.identity()));

Map<Integer, List<History>> memberHistoryById = membersHistory.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(History::getId));
```

Those are both good to keep around, but if you want the Member and the History together, you can then create a combined map, keyed by the Member object. Assuming the natural order of Member is *not* the ID, we need a custom key, which we can do with `TreeMap`.

```java
Map<Member, List<History>> historyByMember = memberHistoryById.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> memberById.get(e.getKey()),
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (a,b) -> a/*this is never called*/,
                () -> new TreeMap(Comparator.comparingInt(Member::getId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67424917/642706) is a good one, using a map to associate a member object with its matching history object.

## Write a class

Alternatively, you could create a class to bind the two objects together.

In Java 16 and later, a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) might do. A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. A record can be declared locally or separately.

```java
record MemberWithHistory ( Member member , History history ) {}
```

Loop your list of members.

For each member, find a matching history. We can do this easily with streams. Make a stream of your history objects, filtering for one whose member identifier matches the identifier of the nth member. An `Optional` is returned carrying the history object if found. Otherwise, if no matching history is found, the optional carries nothing.

If the optional does indeed have a found history object, instantiate a new `MemberWithHistory` record object. Collect that new record by adding to our results list named `mwhs`.

Here is some untested code to get your started.

```java
List< MemberWithHistory > mwhs = new ArrayList<>( members.size() ) ;
for( Member member : members )
{
    Optional< History > historyOptional = histories.stream().filter( history -> history.memberId.equals( member.id ) ).findAny() ; 
    if( historyOptional.isPresent() )
    {
        MemberWithHistory mwh = new MemberWithHistory( member , historyOptional.get() ) ;
        mwhs.add( mwh ) ;
    }
}
```

If you had a large number of items, searching by way of a stream repeatedly might become inefficient. Sorting and possibly deleting from a copy of the histories might be more efficient. But I would not bother for small data size or occasional use.